# CSS linked images are being underlined ("a" display is set to block)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, underline

I have a menu for which I wanted all of the space around the text, within each individual item, to take the user to the specified page. I looked around on the web and found that the best solution is to set the "a" display to block, as follows:

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I have managed to get this working perfectly but want to put images in some of them - like a calendar icon for the events option. I notice it is now underlining the links too. Is there any way to get rid of this? The links have padding-right set to 5px if that helps narrow down the cause / solution.

So all the relevant code is as follows:

```
a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a > img {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.8em;
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

PS It is Google Chrome in which I am having this problem - I have not currently checked it in any other browsers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Images are inline elements, so they are treated as part of the text. It's not the image that is underlined, it's the text that contains the image that is underlined, so it doesn't help to prevent underlining for the image.

You can turn the images into block elements by floating them, then they are not part of the text:

```
a > img {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.8em;
}
```

Comment: Great thank you thank you thank you! Saves me a lot of time and effort. I tried display: block on the images (as advised on another site) but it never even occurred to me to try float.

Comment: You may find that using the background-image and background-position properties is an even better solution. It depends on what the content of the images is I suppose.

Comment: @Casey: Good point. Background images can't be resized though, which might be a limitation in this case.

Comment: The inability to resize was the problem I was facing somewhere else - I had an img with class="expand". I tried to set the src from css (so the src was only specified once and so a change of image would only require one change). However I found that the only ways were to set the src in each case or to use background-image - thats where I discovered that limitation. To be honest, unless I am using the same image for, say, 200 images but only want to change the image in 100 of those, I could just replace the actual image file anyway, and rename the original.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to get rid of the underline text-decoration property for the `a` element, put the link text in a `span` with common class, and apply `text-decoration: underline` to that class.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the kind of answer I got... :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Your span doesn't need a class name, just target it with "a > span {}"

Comment: Guffa got the right answer - using float: left on the images solves the problem!! I was about to add all the spans in too..

Comment: @Casey:  I generally try to never have a span or a div that doesn't have an id or a class, since they're meaningless entities on their own.

Comment: @ngroot A containing element with a class name grants meaning to its children, ie: "ul.menu li a span {}"

Comment: That narrows down its possible meanings, sure.  It still doesn't tell you what the span represents.  A span that would match the selector that you gave is some inline content within links in items in a list that presumably represents a menu.  What the contents of the span within the link represent is missing.

Comment: I agree with ngroot here - I like everything to have just one meaning, not multiple possible meanings. However I personally try to make sure everything has (at least) one class, but tend not to use id as a rule. I believe this enables scalability that, through the id attribute, would not be available. For example you can use classes multiple times in one page, but not ids.

Answer (score 0):

I was running in the same doubt. The `text-decoration` set to `none` works for me:

```
<a href="..." style="text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="...">
</a>
```

As was said befor, you can use a class to make this more generic.

Nice question by the way, It looks totally strange in my website when I saw some minus at the bottom of images. Then I realize that was an underlying.

Answer (score 0):

I tried eveything in the comments to no avail, what worked for me was modifying div which contained all the tags. I have an inkling that they are only underlined when in their absolute default position. Here was the div each tag was wrapped in, no other tricks were applied.

```
.myDiv {
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```