# Keep underline on anchor text but not on font awesome icon in anchor

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have the following markup:

```
<a href="#" title="Feedback" id="feedbacktogglenav">
  Feedback
  <i class="icon-comment"></i>
</a>
```

On hover, I would like the text to be underlined but not the font-awesome icon. I know you can do "text-decoration:none" on the icon (which works) but when you hover on the text part it still adds the underline to the icon. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZEQd/

Comment: Can you post what code you have in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Add the icon via `:before`/`:after`, then it won't be mark of the markup, but rather a pseudo element.

Answer (score 20):

I've discovered a way of doing this without needing an extra span tag, it works in every browser I've tried it in (FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera)... **except** IE8 (I haven't tested in IE 9 or 10 either).

Just declare the icon as display:inline-block, no more underline on hover.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J432G/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" title="Feedback" id="feedbacktogglenav">
  Feedback<i class="icon-comment"></i>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
i:after{
  content: '{icon}';
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Great, this also works without `i`element. My icons are just added via `a:before`.

Comment: **Thank you**. You saved me a lot of heartache with this fix. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

> ...but when you hover on the text part it still adds the underline to the icon. Any ideas?

To get this to work you'd need to contain the link text within a separate element (a `span`, ideally):

```html
<a href="#">
    <span>Feedback</span>
    <i class="icon-comment"></i>
</a>
```

Now you can remove the `text-decoration` from the link completely and assign it only to the `span` (on hover):

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover span {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9eFF/).

Comment: Not the ideal solution, as I can't cere for every link. For example when customers add their texts. Better use the below solutions with display: inline-block. That needs no changes in HTML.

Comment: @Corni that sounds very case-specific. Furthermore Font-Awesome icons are set to `display: inline-block` by default so the below answer isn't all that relevant to the question I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this reliably is to assign text-decoration:none to the first parent element i.e the initial a tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot add a span element (let's assume you just have acccess to CSS), it should work with`float:left or right` on your icon element.

See: [CSS linked images are being underlined ("a" display is set to block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817671/css-linked-images-are-being-underlined-a-display-is-set-to-block)

Answer (score 1):

Someone just responded but deleted their response. The solution was:

```
#utilitynav a i {text-decoration:none;}
```

Thank you mystery person!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZEQd/2/

Just add a span tag in your HTML and you should fine.

**HTML:**

```
    <a href="#" title="Feedback" id="feedbacktogglenav">
       <span class="linkHover">Feedback</span>
       <i class="icon-comment"></i>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.linkHover:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#utilitynav .icon-comment {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
}
#utilitynav .icon-comment:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#utilitynav #feedbacktogglenav {
    margin-right: 12px;
}
```

I added a class to your span for it wouldn't effect future span tags

Answer (score 0):

If you have a situation where you can't use `:before` or `:after` (because the specific icon is set by the content, not by the global style, for example) and you also don't want to have to go in and put `<span>` around the link text everywhere... one other option is to put padding on the link, and absolutely position the icon over the padding.

**HTML**

```
    <a href="#">Feedback <i class="icon-comment fas fa-link"></i></a>
```

**CSS**

```
    a {
      position: relative;
      text-decoration:none;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

    a i {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6bL5m8k/1/

I'm sure there are probably all kinds of special conditions under which this isn't going to work out... but for simple situations it should be fine.